# javascript object undefined

Tags: javascript, couchdb

```
$.couch.urlPrefix = "http://192.168.0.5:5984";
var db = $.couch.db("disastri");

var doc;
 db.openDoc("esempio",{
  success: function(data){
   doc = data;
  },
  error: function(err){
   alert("ERRORE: " + err);
  },
  attachments: true
});

console.log(doc);
```

why? the object doc is undefined?
if I try to initialize doc to an empty object, the value of doc remain the empty object.
I'm sure that is not called the error function, because the browser not show me the alert window.

Comment: These are the essentials of asynchronous methods ... the normal program flow continues with the `console.log()` command at the end while(!) the .openDoc() method is still executed. You have to put the line into the success callback to make sure that doc is defined (because you only define it there ... after the console.log)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**db.openDoc()** - this is the asynchronous call, it means that next operator **console.log(doc)** not wait it complete and run before callbacks functions **success** or **error** calls.

Put **console.log()** into callback:

```
var doc;
 db.openDoc("esempio",{
  success: function(data){
   doc = data;
   console.log(doc); // <--- HERE
  },
  error: function(err){
   alert("ERRORE: " + err);
  },
  attachments: true
});
```

now it will be called when **openDoc()** finished and **doc** defined.

Answer (score 1):

`db.openDoc` works asynchronously - it means that js interpreter doesn't wait for `db.openDoc` to perform its work. It starts asynchronous function, and proceeds to execute following lines of code - while asynchronous still works. So, in this case `console.log(doc);` executes **before** `db.openDoc`. What you need to do is move log invocation into `success` callback:

```
$.couch.urlPrefix = "http://192.168.0.5:5984";
var db = $.couch.db("disastri");

var doc;
db.openDoc("esempio", {
    success: function(data){
        doc = data;
        console.log(doc);
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert("ERRORE: " + err);
    },
    attachments: true
});
```